# Using the definition of sequence convergence, prove that if $\lim{y_n}=2$, then $\lim{3(y_n)^2−2}=10$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Problem: Using the definition of sequence convergence, prove that if $\lim{y_n}=2$, then $\lim{3(y_n)^2−2}=10$.

Note: not allowed to use the Algebraic Limit Theorem, ONLY allowed to use the definition of sequence convergence.

So I understand how to work with the epsilon proof structure when I'm just trying to show one sequence converges, but I'm confused here.

$\lim{3(y_n)^2−2}=10$ in my proof becomes $|{(3(y_n)^2−2)-10|=|3(y_n+2)(y_n-2)|}$.  What I am struggling with is how to go from that to the ending, $< \epsilon$.

I obviously use $\lim{y_n}=2$ so $|y_n - 2|$ < something, although I'm not quite sure what to make it less than.

Can anybody help me with my proof structure here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $|y_n-2|<1$, then $3<y_n+2<5$, so $|3(y_n+2)(y_n-2)|<15|y_n-2|$

Comment: Yes, how do I simplify that to show it is less than $\epsilon$

Comment: When you know $|\cdot|<C\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N_{\varepsilon}$, then ,by convergence of $(y_n)$, there's a $N_{\varepsilon,C}$ such that $|\cdot|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N_{\varepsilon,C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim y_n=2$, we know that,

given $\epsilon$, there is $N$ such that, if $n>N$, then $|y_n-2|<\min\{1,\epsilon/15\}$.

Then, if $n>N$, $|y_n-2|<1$, so $y_n+2<5$, so $|3(y_n+2)(y_n-2)|<3\times5\times\epsilon/15=\epsilon.$

That shows $\lim (3y_n^2-2)=10$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, $|y_n-2|<\epsilon$.

Now, $3|(y_n+2)(y_n-2)|=3|(y_n-2+4)(y_n-2)|<3|(\epsilon+4)\epsilon|=\epsilon_0>0$.

So, we have proved our claim.

Answer (score 1):

0) Since $y_n$ converges to $2$ there is a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|y_n-2|<1$.

1) $|3((y_n-2)+2)^2-2-10|=$

$|3(y_n-2)^2+12(y_n-2)|\le$

$|3(y_n-2)^2|+ 12|(y_n-2)| \le$

$3|y_n-2| +12|y_n-2|=15|y_n-2|$ for $n\ge n_0$.

Let $\epsilon/15$ be given.

Since $y_n$ converges to $2$, there is a $n_1$ s.t. for $n\ge n_1$

$|y_n-2| \lt \epsilon/15.$

For $n \ge \max(n_0,n_1) $

$|3y_n^2-12| \le 15|y_n-2|\lt 15(\epsilon/15) =\epsilon.$

Used: For $|z| <1:$ $|z|^2 \le |z|$.