# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 2} (x^2+2x+4) = 12$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

So, I'm trying to prove the following limit directly using the definition:

$\lim_{x \to 2} (x^2+2x+4) = 12$

---

Proof Attempt:

Define:

$f(x) = x^2+2x+4$

$L = 12$

We have to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that:

$0 < |x-2| < \delta \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$

So, consider the absolute value of the difference:

$|f(x)-L| = |x^2+2x-8| = |(x+4)(x-2)| = |x+4| \cdot |x-2| < \epsilon$

for any $\epsilon >0$.  Now, consider the following:

$|x+4| \cdot |x-2| = |(x-2)+6| \cdot |x-2| \leq |x-2|^2  + 6 \cdot |x-2| = [|x-2|+3]^2-9 < \epsilon$

$ \implies |x-2| < -3 + \sqrt{9+\epsilon}$

Now, pick $\delta = -3 + \sqrt{9+\epsilon}$, so that:

$0 < |x-2|
 < -3 + \sqrt{9+\epsilon}$

Since our required $\delta > 0$ exists so that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$, it follows that the desired limit holds.

Is the proof above correct? If it isn't, how can I fix it?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604437/use-sequence-convergence-of-one-sequence-to-prove-another-converges)

Answer (score 1):

No. Your answer is correct but may be improved. 
Let us clarify something. A point $x$ that satisfies the inequality $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$ is a point "close" to $x_0$ but different from $x_0$. How "close" ? close enough that it lies in a $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$. A $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$ (in this context) is simply the open interval $]x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta[$. So when we say we are going to show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that every point $x$ that satisfies  the inequality $0<|x-2|<\delta$, must also satisfy the inequality $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, we are saying that we are going to prove that there exists a $\delta$-neighborhood "a small enough neighborhood" of the point $x_0$ such that each $x$ that lies in that neighborhood, but different from $x_0$, has an image $f(x)$ that satisfies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

So, the smaller $\epsilon$ is, the smaller $\delta$ will be. That is the closer we require the image $f(x)$ to be to the number $L$, the closer $x$ much be to the point $x_0$.

You can improve your answer in a number of ways. Here is one:

When $|x-2|<\delta$, we have

$|f(x)-L|\leq |x+4| \cdot |x-2| = |(x-2)+6| \cdot |x-2| \leq |x-2|^2  + 6 \cdot |x-2| < \delta^2+6\delta<7\delta < \epsilon$

So, pick $\delta <\epsilon/7$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand. In that last step, you used $\delta^2 + 6 \delta < 7\delta$, employing the fact that $\delta^2 < \delta$. Is that not an undue assumption to make? Like, since $\delta > 0$, that inequality holds specifically when $\delta < 1$. But we're not saying that $\delta < 1$, necessarily. Also, how exactly is my choice of $\delta$ incorrect? Thank you for your answer, by the way.

Comment: We are proving the existence of a $\delta$ for which a certain implication holds, right ? Okay. how about a little stronger statement:  We will prove the existence of a $\delta<1$ such that the property in question holds. We have shown the existence of infinitely many such numbers as we proved that any  $\delta<1$ that satisfies $\delta<7 \epsilon$ works. .

Comment: Uhhhh rightttt, I'm gonna have to stare at that a bit harder lol. But, okay, why is my choice, then, incorrect?

Comment: Actually, having taken a second look at your answer, I find it correct but can be improved. You could estimate $\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{9+\epsilon}+3}<\epsilon/6$. Now, if you learned anything from my answer, please accept it (tick it ).